# Issue with k8s secret while running helm chart from spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker

While running the helm chart from spinnaker, the helm is adding the versioning to the kubernetes secrets as below.

For example secret names is **devops** in yaml file, it is keeping the name as **devops-v001**

But now i am using this secret name in persistent volume yaml file. Since helm is adding versioning to the secret, the pod couldn't able to come up with the original secret name(without versioning.). The pod is keep on failing with the error as "unable to found the secret."

How to disable the versioning of secrets while running from spinnaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the below annotation fixed the issue. This versioning was happening by the spinnaker, need to disable by adding annotation in the yaml file.

annotations:
strategy.spinnaker.io/versioned: "false"